# How to remove duplicated results from multiple orders if a value is not present?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: orders, order_items and order_addons.

I have to fetch all order_items and order_addons of an order in one row.

1 - If an order has 1 product and 2 addons, the result should be:

```
Order no    produt name      addons
123         mobile           cardreader,screen gard
```

2 - If an order has 2 products and 1 addon, the result should be:

```
Order no    produt name      addons
123         mobile,camera    cardreader
```

3 - If an order has 2 products with 1 addon each, the result should be:

```
Order no    produt name      addons
123         mobile,camera    cardreader,datacable
```

4 - If an order has 2 products with 2 addons each, the result should be:

```
Order no   produt name       addons
123        mobile,camera     cardreader,datacable,cardreader,datacable
```

Actually, my query is:

```
SELECT 
    orders.invoice_id AS 'Order Number',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(order_items.product_name, '')) AS 'Product Name',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(order_addons.addon_name, '')) AS 'Addon Name'
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.cart_id = orders.cart_id
LEFT JOIN order_addons ON order_addons.orderitem_id = order_items.orderitem_id
WHERE orders.invoice_id IN ('89161')
GROUP BY orders.order_id
ORDER BY orders.order_id DESC
```

It retrieves duplicated names like in point 1.

```
Order no   produt name       addons
123        mobile,mobile     cardreader,screen gard
```

For point 2:

```
Order no   produt name       addons
123        mobile,camera     cardreader,cardreader
```

If I use this query:

```
SELECT 
   orders.invoice_id AS 'Order Number',
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(order_items.product_name, '')) AS 'Product Name',
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(order_addons.addon_name, '')) AS 'Addon Name'
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_items ON order_items.cart_id = orders.cart_id
LEFT JOIN order_addons ON order_addons.orderitem_id = order_items.orderitem_id
WHERE orders.invoice_id IN ('89161')
GROUP BY orders.order_id
ORDER BY orders.order_id DESC
```

It removes duplicated names and I don't want that if that same name is actually present in order.
Like one order one product and two addons with same name.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to remove duplicates or to keep them ? Cause in title you said "How to remove"...

Comment: create a subquery that pulls your orders first, then another subquery that pulls concat items and third subquery that pulls concat addons. Then join them up

Comment: Hi FLefevre,
by my Query i am getting duplicate value in either of two column if other have more than one value.
so i only want that no of value which is actually present on table.
thanks

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Can you give a real example of referential code, so that i can understand what you want to say?
Moreover don't you think it gonna be too lengthy process.
thanks